# Extending the boot partition in Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, boot-partition

How do I extend the boot partition in Windows XP? [diskpart](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415) does not supporting extending boot partitions.

Answer (score 1):

I used a [GParted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) Live CD.

1. BACK UP YOUR SYSTEM. If anything goes wrong you could lose your data.
2. Shut down and boot from the live CD.
3. Start the default GParted Live OS. Accept defaults or specify options as needed.
4. Once GParted has booted, right-click the partition to expand and select Resize/Move.
5. Resize or move the partition as needed and click Resize/Move.
6. Click Apply and wait for the resize to complete.
7. Reboot the machine back into Windows. Windows will check your drive for consistency. Let it run, it should succeed and reboot your computer.
8. Windows then prompted me that it finished installing new devices and needed to restart, so I restarted.
9. Check your boot partition size. You can run diskmgmt.msc to do this easily.
10. Did it work? Success!